# SSL handshakes on each page load

Tags: ssl, https, connection

As far as I know, after the initial SSL handshake, there is nothing to significantly delay HTTPS and so it performs similarly to plain HTTP. However, in my case it appears that there is always an extra roundtrip when comparing HTTPS to HTTP. So I'm thinking that the server and client are doing a handshake on each page load instead of just once for the entire session.

I dug deeper and found that the Connection header is set to close instead of keep-alive. Can this be causing the server and client to handshake on each page request?

Comment: Alright, but does that mean that on a "close" connection, an SSL handshake takes place on each page load?

Comment: if the connection is begin closed, I think the answer is: yes

Comment: It looks like you are right. We have switched to keep-alive, and now the pages are loading 4 times faster. We have also set the keep-alive timeout to 60 seconds. Although the server is keeping a ton of connections open this way, the performance gain is definitely worth the hardware upgrade we will have to make in order for the server to be able to handle so many open connections.

Comment: as post the comment as an answer

Comment: It doesn't work, send a close don't will ask again for a handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 :` HTTP/1.1 defines the `"close"` connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response. For example, Connection: close in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1) after the current request/response is complete